# mvn install lock How to download normally?

Tags: maven

JDK,maven has been reinstalled and replaced and is still a file download jam.
If the browser can be downloaded

mvn install log:

```
F:\git-java\giiso-entities-fix>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/pom/pom-web/4.3.5.3/pom-web-4.3.5.3.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/pom/pom-web/4.3.5.3/pom-web-4.3.5.3.pom (3.1 kB at 7.6 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/pom/pom-app/4.3.5.3/pom-app-4.3.5.3.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/pom/pom-app/4.3.5.3/pom-app-4.3.5.3.pom (2.1 kB at 29 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/framework-parent/4.3.5.3/framework-parent-4.3.5.3.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/framework-parent/4.3.5.3/framework-parent-4.3.5.3.pom (1.9 kB at 32 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/framework/4.3.5.3/framework-4.3.5.3.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/framework/4.3.5.3/framework-4.3.5.3.pom (2.0 kB at 30 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/pom/pom-dependency-app/4.3.5.3/pom-dependency-app-4.3.5.3.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/pom/pom-dependency-app/4.3.5.3/pom-dependency-app-4.3.5.3.pom (1.9 kB at 29 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/pom/pom-dependency/4.3.5.3/pom-dependency-4.3.5.3.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://maven.giiso.com/repository/maven-public/dev/xwolf/framework/pom/pom-dependency/4.3.5.3/pom-dependency-4.3.5.3.pom (6.9 kB at 109 kB/s)
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.giiso:entity-data-web:jar:1.0.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 4.5.3 @ line 128, column 15
[WARNING] The expression ${parent.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.parent.version} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.giiso:entity-data-web >----------------------
[INFO] Building entity-data-web 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from alimaven: http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom
Downloaded from alimaven: http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom (5.8 kB at 6.3 kB/s)
Downloading from alimaven: http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom
Downloaded from alimaven: http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom (13 kB at 36 kB/s)
Downloading from alimaven: http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/21/maven-parent-21.pom
Progress (1): 13/26 kB
```

download is file:

[image]

Comment: Is this line warning you for your pom.xml ?
`[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 4.5.3 @ line 128, column 15`

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect downloads.And I found a strange problem: the file could only be downloaded to 16k and stuck